# Creating a link in SAS EG

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

I have been unable to find any documentation on creating links in a SAS EG process flow.
Here is an example what I mean by link:

[image]

The ones with the dotted lines are created by right clicking and pressing create a link.

But what do they do? my guess is they make one program run after the data it is linked to is created but I am not sure. What are they used for and is there any consequence for using them?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare those links to traditional CS terms, those links act as a **stack**. They allow to run operations sequentially.

SAS projects sometimes need to be run as a whole project, so you're giving a hint for SAS what to execute, in what order, etc.